# Converting UIImage to (NS)Data produces nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, ciimage

I'm desperately trying to create a qr-code in Swift and convert the image to a (NS)Data-String. It's supposed to act as an image in a HTML file later.
Although the qr-code is created perfectly, the conversion to a data string nevertheless produces `nil`. Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my code?

```
let dataString = "some text or code or whatever"
let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)

if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    filter.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

    if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {

        let bild = UIImage(ciImage: output) // <-- works quite well, image is shown in ImageView
        let bildData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bild, 1.0)  // <-- produces NIL

        let bildString = bildData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        //also tried: let bildString: String = String(data: bildData, encoding: .utf8)!
        print("QRCODE-String: \(bildString)")  // NIL
    }
}
```

I also tried `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` with the same result.

Comment: your data = dataString.data(using: .utf8) .data is nsdata and base64 string you can not convert nsdata.i think

Answer (score 1):

CIImage is filter instructions. CGImage is bitmap data.

UIImage is a wrapper. A UIImage wrapping a CIImage merely contains filter instructions. A UIImage wrapping a CGImage contains bitmap data.

So the problem you are having has nothing to do with NSData. It has to do with UIImage. You are saying:

```
let bild = UIImage(ciImage: output)
let bildData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bild, 1.0)
```

`bild` is not a "real" image; it is merely a kind of wrapper for a CIImage. There is *no data* in the image — all there is is the instructions for the CIImage filter. You can't see anything until you *render* the image into a bitmap. UIImageView might be able to do that for you, but UIImageJPEGRepresentation cannot.

If you want to save the image as data, first *draw* the image into an image graphics context, to get the bitmap. Extract the resulting image, and *now* you have a *real* UIImage backed by CGImage. You can now save its data, because now it *has* data.